# Render CSS Classes w/ No Styles Using Webpack Extract Plugin

Tags: reactjs, selenium, webpack, extract-text-plugin

We use the Extract Text plugin with Webpack 3 and it works great but we recently hired a QA automation engineer who works in Selenium.

We are discussing ways to make selecting elements with Selenium easier but on the front end side. That would involve us writing CSS that we don't use in order to get a class to render on a component. The opposite of what the plugin does essentially.

Is there any way to accomplish this with the plugin? Also open to suggestions if you've worked in Selenium. Maybe even a hack.

**Example:**

```
{ vehicleOptions.map((option, index) => {
  let [label, value] = option
  if (label && value) {
    return (
      <li
        className={ [styles.option, styles[label]].join(' ') }
        key={ `${ label }_${ index }` }>
        <img
          className={ styles.icon }
          src={ `/images/icon-${ label }@2x.png` }
          />
        <p className={ styles.value }>
          { typeof value === 'number'
            ? formatDistance(value, ',', 'mi')
            : value
          }
        </p>
      </li>
    )
  } else {
    return null
  }
```

*In this line* `className={ [styles.option, styles[label]].join(' ') }`, the label for only one of the mapped items applies it's label as a class because it has corresponding CSS. The others do not otherwise based on how Extract Text works.

This is where it becomes difficult for the QA engineer to query the HTML for a particular element.

I had a thought of being able to run `testing` mode but rendering things differently for tests sort of defeats the purpose of testing against real world code that will go to prod.

Answer (score 1):

Similar experience doing this, one thing we ended up doing was adding `data-id="foo"`, then using xpath selectors in our selenium tests.

Then in selenuim you can do things like:
`'//*[@data-id="foo"]'`

or test in chrome with 
`$x('//*[@data-id="foo"]')`

Comment: Ah! I had considered that also... it could work for now... thanks for the comment.

Comment: It's been extremely successful for our case.